# Batch file to create copies of a file

Tags: batch-file, copy, numbered-list

How can I create copies of a video file (.mp4) format, with each copy being numbered alternately?

For example: The file says 01.mp4, so the next copies should be named as 03.mp4, 05.mp4, 07.mp4, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to copy the same file with incrementation, you can try something like this with a batch script:

```
@echo off
set Source=C:\TEMP\MyFile.mp4
set Destination=E:\MyData\
set Filename=MyDoc
set a=1

:loop
if exist %Destination%\%Filename%(%a%).txt set /a a+=1 && goto :loop
copy %Source% %Destination%\%Filename%(%a%).mp4
pause
```

Here is another method using an array to do a copy:

```
@echo off
Title Search for images files
mode con cols=75 lines=5 & Color 0A
set "Folder=%USERPROFILE%\Videos"
set "Destination=%userprofile%\desktop\TestCopy"
If Not Exist "%Destination%" MD "%Destination%
set "Count=0"
set "EXT=mp4"
Set "Msg=Please wait a while scanning for"
Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
For %%a in (%EXT%) Do (
    FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /a-d /b /s "%Folder%\*.%%a"') DO (
        Rem We increment the variable Count
        SET /a "Count+=1"
        rem populate the array variable list with the name of files with their extensions
        set "list[!Count!]=%%~nxf"
        rem populate the array variable list with the name of files without their extensions
        set "listName[!Count!]=%%~nf"
        Call :Scanning "%%~nxf"
        rem populate the array variable listpath with the whole path of files
        set "listpath[!Count!]=%%~dpFf"
    )
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    Copy /y "!listpath[%%i]!" "%Destination%\%%i_!listName[%%i]!.mp4">nul 2>&1
)
Explorer "%Destination%" & Exit
::****************************************************************************
:Scanning %1
Cls
echo( & echo(
echo            %Msg% %1
exit /b
::****************************************************************************
```

Comment: Doesn't the second line in the second script, "Title Search for images files", result in errors?